# get filespecs using a changelist number

Tags: c#, .net, perforce

i have to extract Filespecs using a changeid these FileSpecs are related to files changed in this changelist that i have 
i tried with this code

```
string change = value;
Options optionfilespec = new Options();
optionfilespec.Add(id.ToString(),"");
P4Command commadfilespec = new P4Command(ps, "where", true, change);
P4CommandResult res= commadfilespec.Run(optionfilespec);
```

or can i use this

```
int id = int.Parse(change);
Changelist changelist= rep.GetChange(id);
IList <Perforce.P4.FileMetaData> files= changelist.Files;
foreach (FileMetaData fmd in files)
{ 
            //get the depot path and create instances from filespec            

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second method is correct

```
int id = int.Parse(change);
Changelist changelist= rep.GetChangelist(id);
IList <Perforce.P4.FileMetaData> files= changelist.Files;
foreach (FileMetaData fmd in files)
    { 
                //get the depot path and create instances from filespec            

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter approach is what you want.  I'm not sure if your code snippet is 100% correct but the approach is right.